# Line Graph in windows form app in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, graph, charts, mschart

using vs2008 I am trying to create a line graph using vb in a windows form. I have dragged a chart onto the form, and via the properties window, through the series option have changed the type to the graph that I want, which is line. But all the time the data is displayed as a simple bar chart. How do I remedy this please to get the type of chart that  I want. Thanks for all and any help

Answer (score 2):

Ah blimey at last I've the answer. The graph was originally put on the form via the designer, but as the data changed I redrew the entire graph not realising that I had to include the line    Form1.ChartPlayer1.Series("Series2").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line

Anyway, thanks to all who looked, I realise that from the vagueness of the question it was hard to help, but at least its solved now.